# Wumpus-hunting Masyu

Tags: grid-deduction, video-games, masyu

You are an explorer looking to capitalize on a cave you've discovered.  The goal is to construct a pathway that visitors can take safely.  The problem is that the cave is full of dangers, including a [Wumpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus), but that's what is going to get people to come.  On your last trip through, you made a grid and noted important landmarks in different colors.  Now that you have returned to the safety of your office, you need to [plan out the trail based on the restrictions you've noted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masyu).

[image: Wumpus cave]

Restrictions:

1. Green squares with a P are pitfalls.  Avoid at all costs.
2. Black squares with a B are bats.  They teleport victims to random squares, which is to be avoided.
3. The red square with a W is the Wumpus.  It will eat <strike>anything</strike> anyone in it's square, which is undesirable.
4. Lighter green squares indicate that you are 1 move away from a pitfall.  Acceptable to enter, but watch your step.
5. Lighter red squares indicate that you are 1 or 2 moves from being eaten.  Paths through here should have a good view of the Wumpus so long as it doesn't put us in the square with it.
6. Light grey squares require a straight path through them.  Also, the path before and/or after must be a turn.
7. Dark grey squares require a turn through them.  Also, the path to and from the square must be straight.

Comment: So this is just a Masyu, with lettered squares unenterable?

Comment: Hopefully the rules are clear enough.  1-5 are basically [Hunt the Wumpus rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus#Game_elements) while 6-7 are [Masyu rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masyu#Rules).  Ask if it needs further clarification.

Comment: @Deusovi Essentially, yes.

Comment: It seems like 1-5 boil down to "don't enter letter squares" - do the lighter squares have any effect on the puzzle, and do the different letters have any effects either?

Comment: @Deusovi non-lettered squares are just for decoration, more in line with how the game is played.  Technically, each letter is different, but for the sake of the base puzzle, they all simply mean "Do Not Enter"

Comment: Did you meant **wat*ch* your step**. in 4.

Comment: @RomanGräf I sure did.  Thank for catching that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Unenterable squares here are marked with a `?`.)

Basic deductions:

> [image]

Extending those pieces:

> [image]

Final answer:

> [image]

Comment: The images are missing a ? in the 2nd top 2nd left square, but correct pathway still.

Comment: I have to admit my first thought in response to the question was wondering how you are meant to work out where to enter and exit the cave. Now I see you don't need to worry about that. :)

Answer (score 7):

Just a note that I think there's a slightly different solution to Deusovi's:

> The upper-right section is different. Since it's longer, guests might get thirsty, so there's an opportunity to sell drinks!
>  
>  [image: Masyu solution]

Comment: Interesting. +1